# Wont convert decimal number in string format to float

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with my code and I just don't understand why its not working. The code:

```
total = 0
with open("receipt.txt", "r") as receipt:
    for line in receipt:
        the_line = line.split(",")
        total_product = the_line[4]
        total_product = total_product.translate(None, '\n')
        print total_product
        total += float(total_product)

with open("receipt.txt", "a") as receipt:
    receipt.write("Total of Items:            " + total)
```

The total_product when printed to console is:

```
5.94
807.92
2000.40
0.00
```

What I don't understand is why its not converting each of those to floats and instead prints error to console:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate `'str'` and `'float'` objects

I would love it if someone could tell me how to fix it or/and why its doing it.

Comment: Please include the full error message and the content of the receipt.txt file.

Comment: unrelated: `print >>output_file, "Total of Items:", sum(float(line.split(',')[4]) for line in file)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code actually is successfully converting each of the `total_product`s to a float. The error is in the last line of your snippet where you try to concatenate your string output with the value of your `total` variable (which is still a float). You should use either string formatting (recommended solution):

```
with open("receipt.txt", "a") as receipt:
    receipt.write("Total of Items:            {:.2f}".format(total))
```

or just cast your float to a string:

```
with open("receipt.txt", "a") as receipt:
    receipt.write("Total of Items:            " + str(total))
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `total` variable which is type `float` to a `string`

```
receipt.write("Total of Items:            " + str(total))
```

Here is an example:

```
total = 13.54
str(total)
>> '13.54'
```